# Get the list of dates between two dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i list of dates between two dates in the below table

**Query**

```
select * from Vacation
```

**Output**

```
EmpID   VStart      VacEnd      VacType     PostDate
362330  2017-10-15  2017-10-19  Sick Leave  2017-10-15
```

**Desired Output**

```
EmpID   Date        VacType    
362330  2017-10-15  Sick Leave  
362330  2017-10-16  Sick Leave  
362330  2017-10-17  Sick Leave  
362330  2017-10-18  Sick Leave  
362330  2017-10-19  Sick Leave
```

I have tried to get the desired output using below query but it didn't work

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME
SELECT @Start='2017-10-15' , @End = '2017-10-19'
;WITH DateList
AS
(
SELECT @Start [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Date] +1 FROM DateList WHERE [Date] <@End
)
SELECT dbo.Vacation.EmpID,[Date], dbo.Vacation.VacType FROM dbo.Vacation  INNER JOIN DateList ON DateList.Date = dbo.Vacation.VStart
```

Comment: Why your have declared `@Start` and `@End` when you have already these values in column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to either create a numbers table OR use a subquery or CTE to get a list of numbers, then join your vacation table to that, based on start and end date of vacations.

For example,

```
DECLARE @Vacation TABLE (EmpID INT, VStart DATE, VacEnd DATE, VacType VARCHAR(255));
INSERT @Vacation (EmpID, VStart, VacEnd, VacType) VALUES 
(1, '2017-10-15', '2017-10-19', 'Sick Leave'),
(2, '2017-10-15', '2017-10-16', 'Super Fun Happy Vacation');

SELECT Vacation.EmpID, 
       [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, T.N, Vacation.VStart),
       Vacation.VacType
FROM (
    SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
    FROM sys.objects
) AS T
JOIN @Vacation AS Vacation
    ON DATEDIFF(DAY, Vacation.VStart, Vacation.VacEnd) >= T.N;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just made little change in your query, I haven't tested but seems it will work, please try it.

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME
SELECT @Start='2017-10-15' , @End = '2017-10-19'
;WITH DateList
AS
(
SELECT @Start AS [Date],@Start AS StartDate
UNION ALL
SELECT [Date] +1, @Start AS StartDate FROM DateList WHERE [Date] <@End
)
SELECT dbo.Vacation.EmpID,DateList.[Date], dbo.Vacation.VacType FROM dbo.Vacation  INNER JOIN DateList ON DateList.StartDate = dbo.Vacation.VStart
```